# Given a minimal polynomial of $A$ - calculating for $A$-squared

Tags: matrices, minimal-polynomials

What should be the SOP for this type of question: the minimal polynomial of matrix $A$ is *something*, calculate the minimal polynomial of $A$-squared.

Thanks!

Comment: put all the odd esponent terms on one side and square everything

Comment: @Exodd Thanks! what's the explanation behind it?

Comment: @Exodd Suppose $A^2=0$, with $A\ne0$. Your recipe would give $x^2$ as minimal polynomial.

Comment: I know, in fact for the cases when there are no odd terms, there's no need to do it. I'm trying to figure if those are the only cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic algorithm that is ensured to give the right answer is the following: take the even powers $1=X^0, X^2, X^4,\ldots$ of $X$, reduce each one modulo the minimal polynomial $\mu_A\in K[X]$ of$~A$, and check the resulting polynomials (each one of degree${}<\deg\mu_A$) for linear dependence over the field$~K$. Once you found such a linear dependence (and it is bound to happen for the monomial $X^{2\deg\mu_A}$ if it did not happen before), the coefficients of the relation expressing the remainder of say $X^{2k}$ in terms of previous remainders will give you the coefficients of the minimal polynomial of$~A^2$.

Another way to express this is to take the companion matrix of $\mu_A$, square it, and take the minimal polynomial of the resulting matrix. Unlike the companion matrix itself, it may happen that its square has a minimal polynomial that differs from (so is a strict divisor of) its characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the true algorithm:

Let $q(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$. If $A$ is singular, let $q(x) = x^\alpha p(x)$ with $p(0)\ne 0$.

Take the GCD between $p(x)$ and $p(-x)$, obtaining
$$(p(x),p(-x)) = a(x)\implies p(x) = a(x)r(x)$$
Now, $a(x)$ has only even exponent terms, so $a(x) = b(x^2)$. $r(x)$ has at least an odd exponent term, so $r(x) = r_1(x^2) + xr_2(x^2)$, and putting all the odd terms on one side and squaring you obtain $r_1(x^2)^2 - x^2r_2(x^2)^2$.

The final answer, that is, the minimal polynomial for $A^2$, is
$$ q(y) = y^{\lceil\frac{\alpha}{2}\rceil}b(y) (r_1(y)^2-yr_2(y)^2) $$

---

**First Properties**

let us first suppose that $A$ is already in [Jordan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), since the minimal polynomial doesn't change.

If $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$, then it is in the form
$$
p(x) = \prod_i (x-\lambda_i)^{m_i}
$$
with $\lambda_i$ eigenvalues, and $m_i$ the dimension of the greatest block relative to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. The eigenvalues of $A^2$ can only be $\lambda_i^2$ so its minimal polynomial will be in the form
$$
q(y) = \prod_i (y-\lambda_j^2)^{s_j}
$$
and we have only to find the exponents $s_j$, that is, the greatest size of eigenvalues blocks relative to $\lambda_j^2$ in $A^2$.

*First Case*

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, and $-\lambda$ is NOT an eigenvalue of $A$, then the exponent $s$ of $(y-\lambda^2)^s$ can be determined looking only the $\lambda$ blocks in $A$. Given the largest block of size $m$
$$
B = \lambda I + \begin{pmatrix}0&1&&\\ &\ddots&\ddots&\\ & &\ddots&1\\ &&&0 \end{pmatrix} = \lambda I +J
$$
then
$$
B^2 = \lambda^2 I + 2\lambda J + J^2
$$
that is still similar to $B$, so the biggest block in $A^2$ has still size $s=m$.

*Second Case*

If $\lambda\ne 0$, but both $\lambda$ and $-\lambda$ are eigenvalues of $A$, then the exponent $s$ of $(y-\lambda^2)^s$ will be the greater between the exponents $m$ of $\lambda$ and $-\lambda$ for the First Case

*Third Case*

If $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue, then $A$ has a nilpotent block $J$ of size $m$, and $J^2$ is still nilpotent, but with index $\lceil \frac{m}{2}\rceil$

**Proof**

The algorithm above is correct since

- The exponent relative to the eigenvalue 0 is $\lceil \frac{\alpha}{2}\rceil$ since the polynomial of $A$ have $\alpha$ as exponent of $(x-0)$.
- Let $n_i=\min\{m_i,m'_i\}$, where $m_i$ and $m'_i$ are the exponents of $\lambda_i$ and $-\lambda_i$ eigenvalues of $A$. Then
  $$a(x) = \gcd(p(x),p(-x)) = \prod_i (x^2-\lambda_i^2)^{n_i} = b(x^2) $$
  and $p(x) = a(x) r(x)$ implies that $r(x)$ hasn't opposite eigenvalues, and also implies that $r(x)$ is either constant or has an odd term.
- Now we need to add the exponents left in $r(x)$, so we need to multiply by a polynomial with the same degree of $r(x)$ , and the operation on $r(x)$ described above produce a polynomial in $y$ of the same degree and with the right roots and multiplicity.

Adding all together you obtain that the algorithm is correct.

Comment: What is MCD, the "maximal common divisor"? The common term for that is GCD (G for greatest), $\TeX$ even has the name $\gcd$ built in.

Comment: sorry, I wrote in a hurry, so I used my own language for abbreviations. Yes, it is GCD

Comment: But then your answer is wrong. Take $p(x)=x^3$ as minimal polynomial of $A$, then $\gcd(p(x),p(-x))=\gcd(x^3,-x^3)=x^3=a(x)$ which does not (only) have even exponent terms.

Comment: because 0 is the only number that is also its opposite..@MarcvanLeeuwen by convention, what is the minimal polynomial of the zero matrix?

Comment: The minimal polynomial of the zero matrix is defined as for any matrix (not by a special convention). Since $A^0\neq 0$ but $A=0$ the first dependency relation is $A=0$, so $X$ is the minimal polynomial. (To be pedantic: except for the $0\times 0$ matrix, whose minimal polynomial is $1$.)

Comment: By the way, I don't understand a thing of what you are writing in this answer. Why is it relavant to compute $\gcd(p(x),p(-x))$, and how do you deduce the things you are claiming about this?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Edited